# VS2008 or ReSharper shortcut to delete line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

Which shortcut deletes the whole line where cursor is?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to delete a line without copying the contents has eluded me far to long... There are a few answers here, but they need some clarification:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

- **Deletes** the current line and **does not** copy the text (does not matter if anything is highlighted or not).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

- **Cuts** the current line and **copies** it to your clipboard (does not matter if anything is highlighted or not). This would be the same thing as highlighting the entire line and then using Ctrl+X.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

- If **nothing** is highlighted, then **cuts the current** line and copies it to your clipboard.
- If **anything** is highlighted, then **cuts the highlighted** text and copies it to your clipboard.

HTH's someone.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + L FTW! Thank you so much! I hated using Ctrl + X because I always accidentally overrode whatever was on my clipboard before. Now I may delete old code without hesitation!

Comment: You can always replace the shortcuts in Options->Environment->Keyboard

Answer (score 10):

For VS, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the entire line the cursor's on.

Comment: `Shift + Del` is the same as `Ctrl + X`, it's just the cut command.  If you have no selection, Visual Studio will cut the entire line.  However, if you _do_ have a selection, it will just cut the selection. Gabe's `Ctrl + L` seems like the command that is designed for this scenario...

Comment: Metro's Ctrl + Shift + L is an even better shortcut because it does not affect your clipboard. I think the "correct" answer should be changed to his answer.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is a VS shortcut that will delete the current line and copy it to the clipboard.

The Archives of [Sara Ford's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2005/04/08/406642.aspx) is a goldmine for VS tips.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Enjoy it!!!